# Lyft API get access token

Tags: lyft-api

I need to get an access token in order to ping Lyft API requests and, as per Lyft API documentation, I need a client_id and a client_secret as username and password.

I've used my phone number and validation code as the "username" and "password" for the Lyft account I already have.

I've also tried other options such as my email address but not sure what password should be. Because Lyft accounts do not use passwords, right?

I'm getting below response when I do the curl to get the access token

Much appreciate some help! Thank you.

```js
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The client_id and client_secret are not your own username and password. You will need to go to the Lyft developer portal, create an app, then a client id and client secret will be generated that you can use to obtain an acceess token.